# User's Login date and login time

Tags: login, users

I want to fetch user's login time and login date, is there any command in Unix providing User's login date and User's login time ? this problem i want to perform in Shell-script where username is accepting from the end-user and after checking the availability of user, i would like to fetch that user's login time and login date in different variable and then display using 'echo' command.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For past logins:

```
last "$USER_NAME"
```

Also, the command `who` lists current logins.

If you're looking for the date of the user's last login, some systems provide it directly, for example `lastlog -u "$USER_NAME"` on Linux or `lastlogin "$USER_NAME"` on FreeBSD. It's also available in the output of `finger`, but not in an easy-to-parse form. In any case, it's available in the output of `last` (on many unix variants, `last -n 1 "$USER_NAME"` shows the last login; otherwise you can do `last "$USER_NAME" | head -n 1`). Note that last login may not correspond to the last logout (e.g. a user remained connected from one origin for a long time and made a quick network login recently).

Comment: i know 'who' command is providing the login information of all users , but i wants to have "Login-date" and "Login-time", and i dont wants the user information for past login but for a username accepted from a user and want to fetch the information about that user

Comment: ? last "$username" provides "Login-date" and "Login-time". The second part of your sentence is not clear for me, maybe its my English, maybe its yours... "Username accepted from a user[...]" ?

Comment: @Paresh: I've run out of ways to interpret your question. If my answer still doesn't help, try making your question clearer.

Comment: @Paresh : `last $USER_NAME` will show current users as well. It will show something like `username    ttyp0    192.168.1.100 Tue Sep 13 13:09   still logged in`

Comment: @Gilies let me clear what i want to perform actually, i want to make a shell-script in which i accept user-name as "read $username" and then i want to check whether the user is log-on or not , if yes then i want to fetch their login-time and login-date, thanx for the support

Comment: linux. you beautiful.

Answer (score 4):

On linux, `last -R $username | awk '/still logged in/ {print $3,$4,$5,$6}'` will return nothing if the user is not logged in, otherwise a date/time list for each active session.

Other unixes that don't know the `-R` option to last (which supresses the hostname) will need some modification.